# How to create a chart.js scatter chart with data from two lists

Tags: javascript, python, chart.js

I would like to create a scatter chart in chart.js with the data from two lists. The data from the first list is supposed to be the x values while the data from the second list is supposed to be the y values.

I have tried the following but it does not work. Is there any convenient solution for my problem?

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data: [{
                x: pvols, # first list
                y: prets  # second list
            }]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, does someone know how to reformat my data in order to fit the required format?

Thanks and Kind Regards

Marcel

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) to use a scatter chart, data must be passed as objects containing X and Y properties.

You have to make sure the lists you are passing are in the correct format to be accepted by a scatter chart i.e.

```
var data = [{ x: -8, y: 3 }, { x: 2, y: 8 }, { x: 3, y: 9 }];
```

I would combine your two lists into one object then pass it to the chart.

```
let coords = pvols.map( (v,i) => ({ x: v, y: prets[i] }) )
```

Then pass that when you initilaize your chart

```js
var data = [{ x: -8, y: 3 }, { x: 2, y: 8 }, { x: 3, y: 9 }];

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Scatter Dataset",
        data: data
      }
    ],
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            type: "linear",
            position: "bottom"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your object generation code can be shortened to this: `let coords = pvols.map( (v,i) => ({ x: v, y: prets[i] }) )`

Comment: What is 'povls' ?